# How to use python to fit a curve to data and then get a reusable function from the calculated curve?

Tags: python

I have a dict of values, in this case the key is a time interval and the value is a percentage, the purpose is to see if some value has exceeded a value over some amount of time. This table is used to determine if we sell an investment based on time passed and return obtained, it gets less strict over time.

```
    roi = {
        "0": 0.13,
        "10": 0.07,
        "30": 0.04,
        "50": 0.025,
        "75": 0.017,
        "360": 0.01,
        "720": 0.005,
        "1440": 0
    }
```

For example, in the above table, an investment will have a profit value in a percentage as a ratio, as well as the amount of time that has elapsed since a trade was opened.

Let's say the current time the trade has been opened is 321 minutes and the current profit for that investment is 0.012 (or 1.2%).  As per the above table, I will not sell because at 75 minutes the threshold was 0.017 and it does not drop to 0.01 until 360 minutes. I want to calculate the "between" values for the above steps.

I want to do is take this table and fit a polynomial curve to it (or whatever shape curve seems to make the most sense). I think I can do that part with scipy.optimize curve_fit, what I don't understand how to do would be to use the resulting curve as a function I can re-use.

Ideally I would make a curve and get a resulting function that would resemble f(t) = curve(t) where if i feed it my elapsed time in minutes, it will return a threshold value that I can simple compare to my current profit point.

How can I accomplish this in the least complicated way possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `curve_fit` accepts a function to use, so write a function that you imagine might estimate your data and tell the function to fit things into it.

For example, here's a quick workbench that attempts a couple different formulas (none of which seems to be that good for your data):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize


def poly1(x, a, b):
    return a + (x * b)


def poly2(x, a, b, c):
    return a + (x * b) + (x * c ** 2)


def poly3(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + (x * b) + (x * c ** 2) + (x * d ** 3)


def poly4(x, a, b, c, d, e):
    return a + (x * b) + (x * c ** 2) + (x * d ** 3) + (x * e ** 4)


def exp(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c


def make_estimator(func, data):
    xs, ys = zip(*sorted(data.items()))
    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, xs, ys)
    return lambda x: func(x, *popt)


roi = {0: 0.13, 10: 0.07, 30: 0.04, 50: 0.025, 75: 0.017, 360: 0.01, 720: 0.005, 1440: 0}

for fn in (poly1, poly2, poly3, poly4, exp):
    estimator = make_estimator(fn, roi)
    print(fn.__name__)
    for x, y in roi.items():
        print("  ", x, y, estimator(x))
```

outputs (function name, then X / expected Y / estimated Y):

```
poly1
   0 0.13 0.05327832501447001
   10 0.07 0.0527970341388061
   30 0.04 0.051834452387478275
   50 0.025 0.05087187063615046
   75 0.017 0.04966864344699068
   360 0.01 0.035951853490569216
   720 0.005 0.01862538196666843
   1440 0 -0.01602756108113315
poly2
   0 0.13 0.05327825887535825
   10 0.07 0.05279697258050309
   30 0.04 0.05183439999079287
   50 0.025 0.05087182740108176
   75 0.017 0.04966861166394487
   360 0.01 0.03595195226056802
   720 0.005 0.01862564564576985
   1440 0 -0.01602696758379807
poly3
   0 0.13 0.053278611339440854
   10 0.07 0.05279731865610769
   30 0.04 0.051834733289439286
   50 0.025 0.05087214792277088
   75 0.017 0.049668916214438044
   360 0.01 0.03595207473939817
   720 0.005 0.0186255381393882
   1440 0 -0.01602753506068859
poly4
   0 0.13 0.05327798112102359
   10 0.07 0.05279669504099971
   30 0.04 0.051834122880952016
   50 0.025 0.05087155072090255
   75 0.017 0.04966833552083472
   360 0.01 0.035951682240153104
   720 0.005 0.018625383359278658
   1440 0 -0.016027214402470236
exp
   0 0.13 0.12999999999999978
   10 0.07 0.023857142857142858
   30 0.04 0.023857142857142858
   50 0.025 0.023857142857142858
   75 0.017 0.023857142857142858
   360 0.01 0.023857142857142858
   720 0.005 0.023857142857142858
   1440 0 0.023857142857142858
```